# Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! any Module not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available! any module not working.

Is there any solution?
i am using angular 1.4.7

```
var App = angular.module('my-clinic', [
  'ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ngStorage', 'ngCookies', 'ui.bootstrap', 
  'ngMessages', 'ui.router', 'ui.calendar'
]);
```

---

```
<script src="assets/vendor/ngstorage/ngStorage.js"></script>
```

i had added this file after all angular js files

Comment: Can you show how you use this module?

Comment: var App = angular.module('my-clinic', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngStorage',
    'ngCookies',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngMessages',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.calendar'
]);

Comment: Ok, and where are these modules loaded ? With a `script` tag?

Comment: <script src="assets/vendor/ngstorage/ngStorage.js"></script>  i had added this file after all angular js files

Comment: `ngRoute` and `ui.router` are two different routers; they do not play well together.

Answer (score 0):

When you receive this error, check that the name of the module in question is correct and that the file in which this module is defined has been loaded (either via `<script>` tag, loader like require.js, or testing harness like karma).<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod)</sup>

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.module', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('ui.bootstrap.ctrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.ToolTipText = "Hello, World!";
})
```

```html
<link href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@3/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ui.bootstrap.module" >
  <div ng-controller="ui.bootstrap.ctrl">

    <span uib-tooltip="{{ToolTipText}}" tooltip-placement="bottom" >
      Hover for Tooltip
    </span>

  </div>
</div>
```